# Intentado POST en AndroidStudio (error 400)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, post, http

Estoy realizando una App en Android y necesito conectarme a una API hosteada en localhost.

```
                   /** Creating Connection **/
                URL serverAddress = new URL(link);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) serverAddress.openConnection();
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "Mozilla/5.0");
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

                // JSON
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                jsonObject.put("number", number);

                /** POSTing **/
                OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(jsonObject.toString());
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();
                connection.connect();

                Log.e("AdvancedNotifications", "sending " + jsonObject.toString() + " to " + link);
                Log.e("AdvancedNotifications", "response code: " + String.valueOf(connection.getResponseCode()));
                Log.e("AdvancedNotifications", "response msg: " + connection.getResponseMessage());
```

Y me da error 400 (Bad request).

He probado desde Python con requests y funciona.

Al probar el request desde Python haciendo que imprima el POST en consola, me da esto:

```
192.168.0.158 - - [25/Oct/2018 14:10:35] "POST /call HTTP/1.1" 200 -
{'number': '1642555315'}
```

Y al hacerlo con el request desde la App me da esto:

```
192.168.0.158 - - [25/Oct/2018 14:11:40] "POST /call HTTP/1.1" 400 -
```

**EDIT:**
Al hacer la peticion con CURL, me da este error:

```
{"message": {"number": "Missing required parameter in the post body"}}
```

Comment: connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "Mozilla/5.0"); Aca estas mezclando content type con user agent. Content type debe ser 'application/json' si vas a mandar un json, sino debe ser 'multipart/form-data' o 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Comment: @Juan acabo de cambiar Content type por 'applicaton/json' y me sigue dando error 400, no entiendo que ocurre.

Comment: Por las dudas fijate si $_POST en php tiene lo que estás esperando recibir. Recibir json en php no es lo mismo que mandar un form.

Comment: No estoy usando PhP @Juan, la API está creada en Python. Mira lo que he añadido nuevo al mensaje, porque acabo de probar con CURL y me da ese mensaje.

Comment: Por lo de curl, tendrias que agregar la instrucción por ahi te falta alguna cabecera.

Comment: Python no conozco, pero deberías tener algo así de ese lado: data = request.body.decode('utf-8') received_json_data = json.loads(data). Para mí el tema pasa por que los datos no están llegando donde esperás. También podrias probar esto enviando el dato como form url enconded en lugar de json para ver si lo recibis del lado de python como está.

Answer (score 0):

Así es como yo hago una petición POST:

```
InputStream inputStream = null;
String result = "";
try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // 2. make POST request to the given URL
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(posturl);

        String json = "";

        // 3. build jsonObject
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.accumulate("number", number);

        // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
        json = jsonObject.toString();

        // 5. set json to StringEntity
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

        // 6. set httpPost Entity
        httpPost.setEntity(se);

        // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

        // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

        // 9. receive response as inputStream
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

        // 10. convert inputstream to string
        if(inputStream != null)
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
        else
            result = "ERROR";

    } catch (Exception e) {

        //Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        result="EXCEPTION";
    }

    // 11. return result
    return result;
```

Esta llamada la haríamos desde un HttpAsynkTask.
En mi caso, por parámetro le paso la url a la que vamos a "atacar", es el parámetro posturl.

He incluido en el json tu parámetro number, si tienes que enviar más valores en el json los añades igual que se añade number.

Comment: Es muy parecido a lo que estoy haciendo yo, por no decir lo mismo. Además que HttpClient de Apache ya no se puede usar desde la API 22 de Android

Comment: Realmente no es lo mismo, ni parecido. No utilizamos las mismas clases, ni la forma de hacerlo es igual. De todas maneras, creo que no estás adjuntando bien los parámetros: http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/01/android-httpurlconnection/

Answer (score 0):

El estado HTTP 400 significa *Bad Request*. Es decir, la petición tiene algo erróneo que hace que el servidor la rechace. Los posibles motivos pueden ser muchos: campos que faltan o con valores no válidos, encabezados incorrectos o faltantes, formato del cuerpo del POST incorrecto... etc. Veamos el código:

Lo primero que he notado es que tienes

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "Mozilla/5.0");
```

Que no tiene sentido porque el contenido que mandas es JSON, por lo que debería ser `"application/json"`.

Por otro lado, tu prueba con cURL devuelve

```
{"message": {"number": "Missing required parameter in the post body"}}
```

Aunque no lo indicas, asumo que el HTTP status también es 400 porque está diciéndote que en la petición no has incluido el campo `number` y es requerido (obligatorio).

Comment: Estoy utilizando esto en cURL: `curl -d '{"number":"123456789"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -v http://192.168.0.158:8080/call`

Comment: Se me hace curioso que "number" sea un string... ¿Falla igualmente si no pones las comillas al valor?

Comment: Da el mismo error si quito las comillas.